# Why kotlin cannot expand my typealias?

Tags: java, kotlin, type-alias

I want to write code like below:

```
typealias Just<T> = T  // Error here

val hello: Just<String> = "hello"
```

I got an error says `Kotlin: Type alias expands to T, which is not a class, an interface, or an object`.

I suppose that typealias is a compiler-time feature and should have nothing with type erasure. So why I cannot write `typealias` like this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by declaring such a typealias? It's just a long way to write a type, with no advantages compared to simply writing `String`.

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example of what you are attempting to do? This just seems like a more complicated way than doing type inference or defining it as type String.

Comment: @Todd @yole Maybe it can be convenient when I want to change type `Just` to some wrapper class. I just wonder why I cannot write code like this and I do not want to argue whether I should write like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write code like this because the developers of the Kotlin compiler saw no usecase for supporting type aliases that expand to type parameters (`Just` is basically the only possible declaration of such a type alias), and therefore did not design and implement support for it. This has indeed nothing to do with type erasure.

Comment: Thanks very much. In fact, I cannot write code like `typealias A<T> = T<String>` as well.

Comment: I personally think it's very good that you cannot write code like that in Kotlin, because it would be quite confusing.